# Imgur API BUG Too many Requests by image upload

Tags: api, upload, imgur

I am uploading images through the Imgur API (https://apidocs.imgur.com/) but I am getting a 'Too many Request' (err 429) even thought the previous request returned 'X-Ratelimit-Userremaining=12500'. My understanding is that I should be able to do Post before hitting the rate limit.

Call:  https://api.imgur.com/3/upload 
Request: "errors":[{"id":"","code":"429","status":"Too Many Requests","detail":"Too Many Requests"}]

Call:  https://api.imgur.com/3/credits 
Request: "UserLimit":500,"UserRemaining":500,"UserReset":1584717611,"ClientLimit":12500,"ClientRemaining":12500

It worked for over 5 months. In February 2020 the rate limit was reached twice since then no image could be uploaded.  Anyone a solution?  My imgur users are already getting nervous.

Comment: I’m having the same issue. We’re you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Surely the answer comes late for you but this happened to me and I solved it deploying my app.

Possibly imgur blocks requests coming from localhost.

I deployed my app in AWS without any change and the error dissapeared.